# Maven command line arguments environment variable

Tags: java, maven, environment-variables, maven-3

When I run a mvn build like `mvn clean install`, I notice that in the `System.getenv()` there is an entry with key `MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS` and name being whatever maven phases I specify (`clean install` in this case). However, I cannot find any documentation on this.

Does anyone know where the `MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS` is documented? Does it *always* get set in `System.getenv()` or could it be dependant on the OS, etc?

Comment: you can pass params like this: mvn -Denv=dev clean install. You can find [documentation here](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html)

Comment: @Fede I am looking specifically for documentation on `MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS`, I don't see that in the link you sent me.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I don't think there is documentation about this. You can see `mvn.bat` script and you can see how it is used

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any documentation specific to the environmental variable, but it may be because it is assumed that a user already understands env variables. Just 'set' or 'export' the env var to whatever you use most often.

Windows

```
set MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS=%MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS% clean package
```

Linux

```
set MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS=${MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS} clean package
export MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS
```

Comment: According to a quick github search, this variable exists only for reading the actual command line arguments supplied to the mvn command.  Only the JVM process and its sub-processes can read the variable: https://github.com/apache/maven/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS

Comment: Quick github searches should always be seen as more trustworthy than experience.

Comment: Setting the variable to an unusual goal such as help:help before running the mvn command should result in the command not sensing the unusual goal.